# Cannot get past the $.getJson() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Haven't used json or javascript in a very long time. My javascript is fine before the $.getJson() method and ceases to continue after the method. I am not seeing any errors in the console when I am using the direct path for the JSON.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var myList;
    console.log("here");
    $.getJSON('H:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite1\vegetables.json').done(function (data) {
        console.log("also here");
        myList = data;
        console.log(myList['vegetables'][0].name);

        var uList = document.getElementById("items");
        for (i = 0; i < myList['vegetables'].length; i++) {

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-3 vegetables');

            var name = document.createElement('h3');
            name.innerHTML = myList['vegetables'][i].name;
            div.appendChild(name);

            var description = document.createElement('p');
            description.innerHTML = myList['vegetables'][i].description;
            div.appendChild(description);

            var price = document.createElement('p');
            price.innerHTML = myList['vegetables'][i].price;
            div.appendChild(price);

            var addToCart = document.createElement('button');
            addToCart.setAttribute('value', i);
            addToCart.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
            addToCart.innerHTML = "Add to Cart <img src='glyphicons-203-shopping-cart.png' />";
            addToCart.setAttribute('onClick', 'carrot(this)');
            div.appendChild(addToCart);

           /* <div class="col-sm-3 vegetables" >

                    <h3 id="div1Name"></h3>
                    <p id="div1Description">Carrots are orange </p>
                    <p id="div1Price"></p>
                    <button onclick="carrot(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />Add to Cart <img src="glyphicons-203-shopping-cart.png" />
                </div>*/


            //li.appendChild(panel);
            uList.appendChild(div);
        }
    });

    //var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    //var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
    //newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    //var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    //document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
});
```

When I check the console I'm getting the first print out but not the second and no errors. Not even sure how to debug this. Thanks in advanced.

Here is my json code that I was asked for.

```
{
"vegetables": [
    {
        "name": "Corn",
        "description": "Yellow, delicious",
        "price": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carrots",
        "description": "Orange, kinda tasty",
        "price": "3.00"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lettuce",
        "description": "Gree, leafy",
        "price": "1.75"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Open your Javascript console and check the errors or security warnings.
If I remember chrome doesn't allow the load of Json file from file:// from another location than your html file.

Comment: we are missing some code here (missing closing parenthesis, brackets, etc.) - Please provide an [mcve] to your question

Comment: I believe I have it open. I am not getting any errors or warnings on the js console.

Comment: Add a `fail` branch and print out the error passed to that function. There's a high probability that the ajax call is failing and the error is simply being swallowed. The network tab might also provide some useful hints.

Comment: `'H:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite1\vegetables.json'` is suspicious for a couple of reasons. A) You're interacting with the local file system... this can be problematic in some browsers. B) Where are your escapes for your backslashes? '\' should be '\\' when quoted in Javascript.

Comment: Hey @DylanHoward, could you please share some of the son file content so that I can try the code at my end?

Comment: can you provide full of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to load a file using the path:

```
H:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite1\vegetables.json
```

Due to same origin restrictions on the browser. Access it directly like

```
/vegetables.json
```

Answer (score 0):

based on my understanding of the question, I've tried to provide a solution below. The problem area that I feel is the json format and not how you define the path. Having said so, it is always good to provide a relative path to the json file.

Here is my json file content. Trust me, this is cooked up based on the javascript code that you provided.

```
{
    "vegetables": [{
        "name": "Bringal",
        "description": "Purple colored vegetable",
        "price": "$4"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cauliflower",
        "description": "White flower leafy vegetable",
        "price": "$8"
    }]
}
```

Let me know if my solution help you by any way. Appreciate.